# Simple search-form for bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, flask

I have a linear component I'm developing and I have pretty much all set, [JSfifiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vxvyvyer/):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<div class="input-group">

  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Filter <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      </ul>
  </span>

   <!--action="{{ url_for('search') }}" method="post">-->
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="form-control">

  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Go!</button>
  </span>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now, what I want to achieve is to actually POST the "search" when I press on the Go! button. I have no experience in front-end, so I need your help with this one, I tried to add   but that breaks the bootstrap awesome look.

TL;DR. how to make the Go! button post the text in the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include a form element in your code.

```
<!--Search bar-->
<div class="row" style="margin-top:50px;">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <form class="navbar-form" method="post" action="{{ url_for('search') }}" role="search">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Filter
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </span>             
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="form-control">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Go!</button>
                </span> 
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please find the update of your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vxvyvyer/1/)